# Create .ipa using multiple targets

Tags: ios, bash, watchkit, archive, xcode7

Currently I'm using a bash script to build and archive our iOS application. With the introduction of "Watch" I have found that my script is no longer able to create the necessary .ipa file as it once did.

The build would generate a single .app file which I would use `XCRUN` to invoke `PackageApplication` in order to create the .ipa. Now I'm looking to archive 2 .app files along with 1 .appex file.

Has anyone been able to successfully create an .ipa file via command line/script with multiple .app files?

Using Xcode 6.2

**Update**

Now using Xcode 7 GM along with OSX 10.10.4.

For "TEST" builds I had a difficult time with developers always changing the profiles so I made 2 builds; one from the command line and the other via the IDE (Xcode). I changed the .ipa extension to .zip and compared the 2.

The good build from the IDE had generated a file called "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" which had all the signing identities defined correctly.

I copied this file out to a different directory and use it to inject with all other subsequent builds. The builds now are able to be loaded on the phone & watch for testing.

Below is an example of how to do it. A bit of a hack but it works.

```
security -v unlock-keychain -p "password" "keychainPath"

xcodebuild -configuration Test -scheme YourAppName -archivePath somePath/YourAppName.xcarchive archive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat IPA -archivePath somePath/YourAppName.xcarchive -exportPath somePath/YourAppName.ipa

unzip -o somePath/YourAppName.ipa -d somePath

cp somePath/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent somePath/Payload/YourAppName.app

zip -qr somePath/YourAppName.ipa Payload
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution which is working on the archive file of the project which has watch, app and extension.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath AppName.xcarchive/ -exportPath AppName.ipa -exportFormat ipa -exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity
```

This command basically uses same signing identify and provisioning profile to export the ipa from raw xcarchive file.

Answer (score -1):

We have sort of work around to generate .ipa that contains iPhone app and apple watch app.

After the .app is generated using Xcodebuild, in the bash script we do the following

A)

1. Create Directory with Application Name
2. Inside Application directory create sub directory named Payload
3. Copy .app into Payload directory

B)

4. Inside Application directory create sub directory named WatchKitSupport as a sibling to Payload.
5. Copy a binary named "WK" from the iOS 8.2 SDK in Xcode to your new WatchKitSupport directory. This binary can be found at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/Library/Application Support/WatchKit/
6. Make sure the "WK" binary is not touched/re-signed in any way. This is important for validation on device.
7. Zip the application folder
8. Rename .zip to .ipa

When expanded the IPA should contain (at least):
xxx.ipa
|________Payload/
|________WatchKitSupport/
                   |_____WK

This works for us.